# jQuery error : Cannot read property undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a custom button on Account layout to test popping up a jQuery modal dialog box.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js')} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/js/functions.js')} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/resource/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js')} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/resource/jQuery/ui/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js')} 

requireCssFile('/resource/jQuery/ui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.css'); 

function requireCssFile(filename) { 
var fileref = document.createElement('link'); 
fileref.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet'); 
fileref.setAttribute('type', 'text/css'); 
fileref.setAttribute('href', filename); 
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fileref); 
} 

var j$ = jQuery.noConflict(); 

var j$modalDialog = j$('<div></div>') 
.html('Be Apex my friend!') 
.dialog({ 
autoOpen: false, 
title: 'My Modal Dialog', 
resizable: false, 
width: 400, 
height: 400, 
autoResize: true, 
modal: true, 
draggable: false 
}); 

j$modalDialog.dialog('open');
```

I have been following this article as to how to issue a jQuery modal dialog box from Standard Page Layout.

http://www.valnavjo.com/blog/modal-dialog-on-a-standard-salesforce-page/

Upon clicking on this custom button I am getting the following error.

[image]

Can someone let me know what is the issue ?

Comment: you are trying to access the jQuery from your static resources....did you have jQuery libraries (zip folder) in your resources?

Comment: That was it..Forgot to add them ..thanks..you can put as answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to have jQuery libraries included in your static resources file.

For reference [Adding jQuery To Your Force.com Application](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2011/01/adding-jquery-to-your-salesforce-application.html)